# How can I test a debounce function with Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component where test coverage says I need to test lines 24 and 25:

```
class TableToolbarComp extends Component {
  state = {
    shipmentId: '',
  };

  debouncedSetFilters = debounce(() => {
    const { applyFilters } = this.props; // LINE 24
    applyFilters(this.state);            // LINE 25
  }, 750);

  updateShipmentId = ev => {
    this.setState(
      {
        shipmentId: ev.target.value,
      },
      this.debouncedSetFilters,
    );
  };

  render() {...}
}
```

And the test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    applyFilters: k => k,
  });

...

  it('should trigger button click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableToolbarComp {...props} />);

    wrapper.instance().debouncedSetFilters(750);
    wrapper.instance().updateShipmentId({ target: { shipmentId: '124' } });
    wrapper.instance().props.applyFilters({ shipmentId: '124' });
  });
```

And I am not getting any errors, it just says those 2 lines need coverage.

I already attempted to called `debouncedSetFilters` and `applyFilters` on the test but it's still returning those 2 lines as uncover.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function calls cannot be tested efficiently without spies. It should be:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    applyFilters = jest.fn();
  });
```

In order to test asynchronous time-sensitive function, timer mocks should be applied:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

const wrapper = shallow(<TableToolbarComp applyFilters={applyFilters} />);

wrapper.instance().debouncedSetFilters();
wrapper.instance().debouncedSetFilters();
expect(applyFilters).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
jest.advanceTimersByTime(750);
expect(applyFilters).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Then `debouncedSetFilters` can be stubbed in `updateShipmentId` test.

Comment: Why two calls of `wrapper.instance().debouncedSetFilters();` or is it a typo?

Comment: That's how debounced function can be tested. Two calls should result in one applyFilters call.